# How to build command line utility

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, frameworks

I have a framework that includes a command line utility. This application is called by third party applications to perform certain tasks. There is no way I can go around not having this utility.

I've written the code and added the .m file to my project. I created a new target for it of the Core Foundation type. I added the right files to the Compile Sources section under Build Phases. But for some reason, Xcode doesn't build my utility. Whenever I build the framework and expand the Products group, the command line utility is left red.

How do I force Xcode to build it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't sure if I understand you correctly.
You have a framework with utility and you want to include that utility to your boundary? Than you probably need to add that utility to "Copy Files" section of "Build Phases"
Or you want to build utility in your project?
Than you probably need to add "Command line tool" target to your project.
**Edit**: To link two targets just add dependcy target to the "Target Dependencies" section of "Build Phases" of the main target.

Comment: I've added the "Command line tool" target but the project still isn't being built.

Comment: May be you need to add this "Command line tool" target to the "Target Dependencies" in the "Build Phases" of your main target?