# How to make my code discover an embedded utility?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, frameworks

Continuing with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613779/how-to-build-command-line-utility) question.

I have a command line utility embedded in a framework. That utility is used by third parties to handle some processing. There is no way I can not use that utility.

My problem is, I don't know how to locate my utility on disk. It's bundled in a framework within my main app, but I am not sure how to get the right path.

Halp?

Comment: To clarify, you want to programmatically get the path to the command-line executable from within the code of your main application bundle? Whereabouts is the command-line executable located inside the framework (for example, the `Resources` folder, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you've set a proper bundle identifier (`CFBundleIdentifier`) entry for the `Info.plist` file of the .framework, you can use `NSBundle`'s [`bundleWithIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleWithIdentifier%3a) method to obtain the bundle representing the framework, then use [`pathForResource:ofType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource%3aofType%3a) to get the path to the executable. Just make sure you give the framework a unique bundle identifier (different from your main app bundle's bundle identifier).

For example, say I have an app bundle `CoolApp.app` that has a `CFBundleIdentifier` of `com.blah.CoolApp`. It has a `TextureKit.framework` framework which is at `CoolApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/TextureKit.framework`, and has a `CFBundleIdentifier` of `com.blah.TextureKit.framework`. Inside the `Resources` folder of the `TextureKit.framework` is an executable named `textureUtility`. I could use the following code to get the full path to `textureUtility`:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.blah.TextureKit.framework"]
                           pathForResource:@"textureUtility"
                                    ofType:@""];
```